# Products of 3- and 4-vectors: consistency of the metric signature

Tags: special-relativity, vectors

***EDIT for clarification of question***: Is it correct that the square of a 3-vector picks up a minus sign in the signature $\{+---\}$?  If not, doesn't that mean the $\{-+++\}$ convention is preferred (better) because it gives the right answer for products of 3- and 4-vectors?

Let the metric be the Minkowski metric in signature $\{+---\}$ with $c=1$.  For some 4-vector $v^\mu=(v^0,v^1,v^2,v^3)$, we have

\begin{align}
v^2&=v^\mu v^\nu\eta_{\mu\nu}\\
&=v^\mu \big( v^0\eta_{\mu0} + v^1\eta_{\mu1} + v^2\eta_{\mu2} + v^3\eta_{\mu3}  \big)\\
&=v^\mu \big( v^0\delta_{\mu0} -v^1\delta_{\mu1}- v^2\delta_{\mu2} -v^3\delta_{\mu3}  \big)\\
&=v^\mu \big( v^0 -v^1- v^2 -v^3 \big)~~.
\end{align}

Noting that the individual components of $v$ are scalars multiplied by the four unit vectors $\hat e^\mu$, we define $v_\mu=(v^0,-v^1,-v^2,-v^3)$ so that

\begin{align}
v^2&=v^\mu v_\mu\\
&=v^0v_0+v^1v_1+v^2v_2+v^3v_3\\
&=\big(v^0\big)^2-\big(v^1\big)^2-\big(v^2\big)^2-\big(v^3\big)^2~~.
\end{align}

However, if we consider a 3-vector $p^k=(v^1,v^2,v^3)$ such that $v^\mu=v^0+p^k$, we have

\begin{align}
p^2&=p^k p^j\eta_{kj}\\
&=p^k\big(  v^1\eta_{k1} + v^2\eta_{k2} + v^3\eta_{k3}  \big)\\
&=p^k \big( -v^1\delta_{k1}- v^2\delta_{k2} -v^3\delta_{k3}  \big)\\
&=p^k \big( -v^1- v^2 -v^3 \big)~~.
\end{align}

for which we would define $p_k=(-v^1,-v^2,-v^3)$ so that

\begin{align}
p^2&=p^k p_k\\
&=v^1v_1+v^2v_2+v^3v_3\\
&= -\big(v^1\big)^2-\big(v^2\big)^2-\big(v^3\big)^2~~.
\end{align}

However, this is not the correct answer.  The correct answer is

$$p^2=\vec p\cdot \vec p= \big(v^1\big)^2+\big(v^2\big)^2+\big(v^3\big)^2~~,$$

where we have implicitly taken the $\eta_{jk}$ part of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ to have signature $\{+++\}$.  What is going on here?  How is this reconciled?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117408/discussion-on-question-by-hodop-smith-products-of-3-and-4-vectors-consistency).

Answer (score 0):

There is a free choice between $\{+ - - - \}$ and $\{- +++ \}$. The reason behind it is that product of the eigenvalues of both of them is $-1$ . But $\{- - - \}$ and $\{+ ++ \}$ are not the same because the product of the eigenvalues of the first one is $-1$ and the other one is $+1$.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that the two 3-metrics are not the same.  Could you say little more?  How am I to interpret the product of two 3-vectors when the spatial part of the 4-metric has signature $\{---\}$?  What is the significance of the product of the eigenvalues?

Comment: The product of the eigenvalues is the determinant. If you change the determinant of the metric you totally change it. The determinant of the metric is related to the Jacobian matrix and the volume.

Comment: If the $\{+---\}$ signature for $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is such that that $\eta^{jk}$ is not acceptable as the metric of Euclidean space, then shouldn't we conclude that the metric of spacetime is definitively written in the $\{-+++\}$ convention which supports products of 3- and 4-vectors?

Comment: each convention has its own advantages and disadvantages. In many cases we do not care about $\eta^{ij}$ and never work with the 3-vectors. In general, many thing in physics are jut a matter of convenience and tradition (for example charge of electron can be chosen to be positive). At the end of the day both conventions explain the same physics. What makes a something correct or not is experiment and only experiment.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments you are using the summation notation incorrectly. The following is true:

$$\begin{align}
v^2 &=: v^\mu v^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu}
\\ &= v^\mu v_\mu
\\ &= v^0v_0-v^1v_1-v^2v_2-v^3v_3
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

On the other hand if we consider a $3$-vector like the momentum, $\vec p$, we are no longer working $4$-dimensions, and so the correct metric to be using is the [Euclidian metric](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanMetric.html#:%7E:text=The%20Euclidean%20metric%20is%20the,between%20any%20two%20vectors%20in%20.), $\delta_{ij}$:

$$\begin{align}
\vec p^2=:p^ip^j\delta_{ij}=p^ip_i=p^1p_1+p^2p_2+p^3p_3.
\tag{2}\end{align}$$

We note that the square of the *four*-momentum $(p)$ will "contain" the square of the *three*-momentum $(\vec p)$ since $p=(p^0,\vec p)^T$ (in slightly abusive notation), such that:

$$p^2=p^0p_0-\vec p^2 \tag{3}.$$

Comment: It's seems like you are saying that I am summing with the wrong object rather than that I have not used the notation correctly.  If there is an error in my use of the notation, could you identify it?  If you're saying that I'm simply using the wrong object, then I agree and my whole question was to call attention to the fact that using the spatial part of the $\{+---\}$ 4-metric is wrong.  I am wondering, why is it wrong?    If I had chosen 4-signature $\{-+++\}$, I would have gotten the right answer so I highly doubt that I am not using the notation correctly.  Why is one signature preferred?

Comment: Note that in special relativity we are working in $\Bbb R^{1,3}$, which isn't as friendly of a space as $\Bbb R^4$. There are two metric conventions on $\Bbb R^{1,3}$, $(+,-,-,-)$ and $(-,+,+,+)$, neither of them is "preferred". Note that the metric on Minkowski space, $\eta$, technically cannot contract 3-vectors which are elements of $\Bbb R^3$. Your indices do not match in your first and fourth line.

Comment: You may note that if we consider the 4-vector $v=(0,v^1,v^2,v^3)$ we can contract *this* with $\eta$, but we should not in general expect to get the same result as contracting $(v^1,v^2,v^3)$ in $\Bbb R^3$, because it is a *different* space.

Comment: Yes, you are getting at the issue I tried to address with $v^\mu=v^0+p^k$.  I want to to take $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a subspace of Minkowski space.  It seems like the $\{-+++\}$ metric signature will let me do that but $\{+---\}$ will not let me do it.  This surprises me because usually they say the choice of signature is irrelevant.  As I understand it, the 3-space ***has*** to be a space of the 4-space if we are doing physics in space and spacetime.  In fact, it is completely standard to write the 3-metric as the Latin letter part $\eta^{jk}$ of 4D Greek lettered $\eta^{\mu\nu}.$

Comment: The choice of signature on $\Bbb R^{1,3}$ is convention, that doesn't guarantee that subspaces are not affected by this choice. I do not know how the subspaces of $\Bbb R^{1,3}$ look, but you will need to be careful since, again, $\Bbb R^4$ and $\Bbb R^{1,3}$ are definitely different spaces and so you shouldn't expect that their subspaces are nicely related either.

Comment: In the summation convention it is typical to write summations over the index $\{1,2,3\}$ with Latin indices, correct, but that does *not* necessarily mean that $\eta_{ij}$ *is* the Euclidean metric, do not let the notation fool you.

Comment: @Charlie $v^0v_0-v^1v_1-v^2v_2-v^3v_3$ Your signs are wrong. A contraction is always a simple sum: $$v^\mu v_\mu\equiv\sum_{\mu=0}^3v^\mu v_\mu=v^0v_0+v^1v_1+v^2v_2+v^3v_3.$$ This is true regardless of metric, sign convention, dimension, etc. It is the core concept of the Einstein summation convention. The negative signs enter when you are writing this sum in terms of only contravariant components or only covariant components.